# Align column of numbers, negative numbers, decimals and percentages in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

My list of numbers contains the following:

```
48.8
4.19
(0.36)
4.52%
```

and I want them all to align by decimal.  As far as I can tell it is not possible in a single step and the best I can do is paste it into Word and use the align by decimal feature.  Can anyone provide a way to do this in Excel, please?

Comment: Try this link: [Decimal Tab Alignment](http://excel.tips.net/T002765_Decimal_Tab_Alignment.html)

Comment: "You can also format as accounting and remove the dollar sign" -- Comment added by **Bryan** at bottom of the [updated article](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T012318_Decimal_Tab_Alignment.html) pertaining to the 2007 and 2010 versions. (Tested with 2010)